# Resize feature vector from neural network

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to perform a task of approximation of two embeddings (textual and visual).
For the visual embedding, I am using VGG as the encoder. The output is a `1x1000` embedding. For the textual encoder, I am using a Transformer to which output is shaped `1x712`. What I want is to convert both these vectors to the same dimension **512**.

```
img_features.shape, txt_features.shape = (1,1000),(1,712)
```

How can I do it in *PyTorch*?
Add a final layer in each architecture that models the output to 512?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could either apply a differentiable PCA operator such as [`torch.pca_lowrank`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.pca_lowrank.html).
- Alternatively, an easier solution is to use two fully connected adapter layers to learn two mappings. One for you image features `1000 -> n`, the other for textual features: `712 -> n`. Then you can choose a fusion strategy to combine the  two features shaped `(1,n)`: either using concatenation, point-wise addition/multiplication (in thoses cases `n` should be equal to `512`. Esle you can learn a final mapping `n*2 -> 512`.